# Class function to take pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, class

I would like my class to have a function taking an external dataframe.

```
df = {'subject': ['foo', 'bar'], 'object': ['bar', 'foo']}
cond_df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)


class Block:                
    def __init__(self, name = 'no_name', dimension = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], relation = [] ): 
        
        self.name = name   
        self.dimension = dimension
        self.relation = relation
        
    def get_relation(self, cond_df):
        for i in range(len(cond_df['subject'])):
            if cond_df['subject'][i] == name:
                relation.append([cond_df['object'][i], 0]) # if the entity is the subject, label it '0' for parent
            elif cond_df['object'][i] == name:
                relation.append([cond_df['subject'][i], 1]) # if the entity is the object, label it '1' for child
        return(relation)
                
a_block = Block()

a_block.get_relation(cond_df)
```

so far it returns me 'list' object is not callable.

I am new to class definition, could you help?
Thanks

---

Now that I have added the "self." keyword the get_relation function works. However, it writes self.relation as a class variable instead of an instances variable. What should I change?

```
class Block:                
    def __init__(self, name = 'no_name', dimension = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],relation = [] ): 
        
        self.name = name   
        self.dimension = dimension
        self.relation = relation
        
    def get_relation(self, cond_df):
        for i in range(len(cond_df['subject'])):
            if cond_df['subject'][i] == self.name:
                self.relation.append([cond_df['object'][i], 0]) # if the entity is the subject, label it '0' for parent
            elif cond_df['object'][i] == self.name:
                self.relation.append([cond_df['subject'][i], 1]) # if the entity is the object, label it '1' for child
        return(self.relation)
                
a_block = Block(name = 'foo')

a_block.get_relation(cond_df)
```

Comment: You have 2 things named `relation`, a property of the `Block` class and a method of it. rename one of them.

Comment: I corrected this mistake, still I'm stuck with the same error.

Comment: Please update the code to match this change

Comment: I have added `self.` before `relation` and `name` variables in `get_relation` method and everything works fine